# Database design, shound I use varchar for Primary Key in this case?

Tags: database, database-design

Im building a webpage where users will be able to create accounts, and every account will have its own subdomain. So there could be URL-s like this:

```
www.user1.domain.com
www.user2.domain.com
...
```

They will have their own pages too, like this:

```
www.user1.domain.com/url-1/
www.user1.domain.com/url-2/
www.user2.domain.com/url-3/
...
```

So I need to store account_url and page_url in database.

I did it like this, I have users, accounts and pages tables.

This is how my tables look like:

USERS:

```
user_id     PK
user_name
user_pass
...
```

ACCOUNTS:

```
account_id  PK
user_id     FK
account_url
account_name
account_type
...
```

PAGES:

```
page_id     PK
user_id     FK
page_url    
page_name
page_content
...
```

Now the problem is this, since I get url like this:

```
www.user1.domain.com/page-url/
```

The only information I can fetch from url is account_url and page_url since its in URL, dispatcher/router gets these two variables. account_url is subdomain, and page_url is segment after domain.

Since there will be multiple users I always need to get that user_id so I can update/delete rows that belong to them. So I need to update page_content where user_id belongs to this user and page_url is the one from URL.

But I dont have user_id. And when I would like to update page_url_content, first I need to find user_id, like this:

```
SELECT user_id FROM accounts WHERE account_url = something
```

And then when I have user_id I can update content of a page or do any other action.

So is this a good design?
Its normalized and clean, but when Im using this in every action inside controller I need to fetch user_id first joust to be able to do a real query I wanted.

Now, I could use account_url for Primary Key, and have all tables relate to that primary key. So when I get URL I already know the Primary key since its in the URL.

Is this a good case to use Primary Key in URL, or Im doing something wrong?

Comment: Could you clarify your intended relationship between users, accounts and pages? I don't understand why a user could have multiple accounts...

Comment: I am assuming the user needs to be logged in to update anything, why can you not pass the logged in user_id when you need to make the calls(store the user_id as a session variable when they are logged in)

Answer (score 2):

I prefer to always have my primary ID keys as integers for joins.  That said, there are a bunch of ways to help make your site snappy.

- You could index the account_url column so look ups are more efficient.
- Or you could cookie the users ID and use that value instead of querying the database each time. Granted, you would want to do some session tracking so someone can't spoof someone else.
- One presumes the user will be in control of the name of the subdomain, so embedding the user ID into the subdomain name probably wouldn't be effective otherwise it is also an option.
- You could keep user ID and user account_url in a separate table and cache that table so you don't hit the database for the vast majority of lookups.

My recommendation would be to keep the primary key the integer, index the account_url and identify a page load target time; say completing all database access and page rendering in under 1.500 seconds.  When your site starts to respond over your threshold, then you can analyze your site to see where the actual problems lie and address them then.

Comment: 1.5 seconds is an _amazingly long time_ in the Internet. I would say that if you are not sending a response back within .5 seconds (500ms) you are taking too long.

Comment: @cdeszaq; no arguments  :-)  It's all relative, yes?

Comment: Unfortunately, it isn't. [Google](http://googleresearch.blogspot.com/2009/06/speed-matters.html) and [others](http://munchweb.com/effect-of-website-speed) have found that page load speed has a direct correlation with converting users (regardless of what "converting" means). Google will also [rank](http://googlewebmastercentral.blogspot.com/2010/04/using-site-speed-in-web-search-ranking.html) a slower site lower than an equivalent site in it's search results

Comment: Quite so.  My own work experience has shown that highly successful websites can generate significantly profitable results while being nowhere near the sub-one second times.  It depends upon the users' expectations and the value they believe they will derive from the experience.  OTOH, I've seen usage drop significantly with other sites when page load time exceeded 1500 ms.  So, with all due respect, I cannot accept that there are absolutes; hence, it is all relative.

Answer (score 1):

In general, leave the database normalized as much as possible. If and when you can provably show (using metrics and actual measurements) that you *need* to denormalize for performance reasons, then *think* about doing that.

In this case, if you have a m-1 relationship between a domain and a user's account, you can effectively treat the domain as a user ID; you just have to join things in the right way. (and by m-1, I mean a single domain can only be "owned" by 1 user).

The key thing is that you don't *need* to get the user_id because you can get to it by joining the ACCOUNTS table as needed since it ties the domain to the user_id.

Lastly, to your question about using the domain as the primary key, you *can* do this, since a domain is required to be "unique", but you have a minimal overhead and much more flexibility by using a surrogate primary key.

Answer (score 0):

You have two totaly separate issues. Mapping Subdomains and pages to a user is the easier of the two. The more difficult issue is "State". You need to create state database (or similar module) to keep track of which user is currently logged in and if they are still logged in when an update is received.

JZ touched on this in his comment. Don't confuse these two issues, they are separate and should betreated as such.